# extend data with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have this data.table

```
library(data.table)

data.table(
  id = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2)),
  begin = c(1, 4, 8, 1, 11),
  end = c(3, 7, 12, 10, 12),
  state = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A")
)
```

I would like to have this output :

```
data.table(
  id = c(1, 2),
  m1 = c("A", "B"),
  m2 = c("A", "B"),
  m3 = c("A", "B"),
  m4 = c("B", "B"),
  m5 = c("B", "B"),
  m6 = c("B", "B"),
  m7 = c("B", "B"),
  m8 = c("A", "B"),
  m9 = c("A", "B"),
  m10 = c("A", "B"),
  m11 = c("A", "A"),
  m12 = c("A", "A")
)
```

Those who used to do sequence analysis may have recognized that I'm trying to do what `seqformat` do in the `TRaMiNeR` package would do, but with higher performance due to use of `data.table`

Comment: I doubt you can get high performance for reshaping a table to wide format without a specialized package. If you are willing/able to work with long format data, though, there is `DT[, .(seq = seq(first(begin), last(end)), v = inverse.rle(.(values = state, lengths = end - begin + 1L))), by=id]`

Comment: An alternative to @Frank's option: ```dt[, unlist(Map(`:`, begin, end)), by = .(id, state)]``` (see also my answer)

Answer (score 5):

One option with `data.table` would be to `melt` the dataset after creating a sequence column, then grouped by 'i1', 'id', 'state', get the `seq`uence of `first` and `last` 'value', `dcast` it from 'long' to 'wide'

```
dt1 <- melt(dt[, i1 := seq_len(.N)], id.vars = c("i1", "id", "state"))[,
      paste0("m", seq(first(value), last(value))), .(i1, id, state)]
dcast(dt1, id ~ V1, value.var = "state")[]
#    id m1 m10 m11 m12 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 m7 m8 m9
#1:  1  A   A   A   A  A  A  B  B  B  B  A  A
#2:  2  B   B   A   A  B  B  B  B  B  B  B  B
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using the `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

dat <- data.table(
  id = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2)),
  begin = c(1, 4, 8, 1, 11),
  end = c(3, 7, 12, 10, 12),
  state = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A")
)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(Index = map2(begin, end, `:`)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(Index = str_c("m", Index)) %>%
  select(id, state, Index) %>%
  spread(Index, state) %>%
  select(id, str_c("m", 1:(ncol(.) - 1)))
dat2
#   id m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 m7 m8 m9 m10 m11 m12
# 1  1  A  A  A  B  B  B  B  A  A   A   A   A
# 2  2  B  B  B  B  B  B  B  B  B   B   A   A
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution:

```
dt[, unlist(Map(`:`, begin, end)), by = .(id, state)
   ][, dcast(.SD, id ~ sprintf("m%02d", V1), value.var = "state")]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    id m01 m02 m03 m04 m05 m06 m07 m08 m09 m10 m11 m12
> 1:  1   A   A   A   B   B   B   B   A   A   A   A   A
> 2:  2   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   B   A   A
> ```

---

It is possibly better to keep the data in long format. Long format is often easier to work with in R later on in your data processing/analysis.

You could achieve that with just:

```
dt[, unlist(Map(`:`, begin, end)), by = .(id, state)][order(id, V1)]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     id state V1
>  1:  1     A  1
>  2:  1     A  2
>  3:  1     A  3
>  4:  1     B  4
>  5:  1     B  5
>  6:  1     B  6
>  7:  1     B  7
>  8:  1     A  8
>  9:  1     A  9
> 10:  1     A 10
> 11:  1     A 11
> 12:  1     A 12
> 13:  2     B  1
> 14:  2     B  2
> 15:  2     B  3
> 16:  2     B  4
> 17:  2     B  5
> 18:  2     B  6
> 19:  2     B  7
> 20:  2     B  8
> 21:  2     B  9
> 22:  2     B 10
> 23:  2     A 11
> 24:  2     A 12
> ```

(where the `[order(id, V1)]`-part isn't necessary)

---

Used data:

```
dt <- data.table(
  id = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2)),
  begin = c(1, 4, 8, 1, 11),
  end = c(3, 7, 12, 10, 12),
  state = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A")
)
```